# Read environment variables outside of next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, dotenv

I am using next js as the basis for my application. My environment variables work as long as they are read within the scope of next js but I need to use them inside a script that does not use next js.

With dotenv we can do the following:

`require('dotenv').config();`

Which parses the environment config files and allows you to get the variables from `process.env`.

Because I am using next js I would prefer to use their environment variable implementation instead of adding a second way to store environment variables.

Is there an equivalent of `require('dotenv').config();` for next js or another way to load the environment variables outside the scope of next js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I went into the git repo of next js and found a way to do it.

You have to install `@next/env` and then run `require('@next/env').loadEnvConfig('./');`

Comment: which uses `dotenv` itself...